# Google Apps Script Calendar get specific event with eventID

Tags: google-apps-script

with Google Apps Script ( calendar )
How can I get specific event with eventID

I can't find on references

Answer (score 2):

It's right here: [GAS-get event series](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getEventSeriesById(String))